# Get Firebase Children Count

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the children count of the node inside another node.

The following is the structure of my node.
[image]

I want to get the count of children under the postComment.
Which means I might have default2, default3, default4 under postComment.
I want to get the number of postComment.

I use the code >>

```
mPostDatabase.child(postID).child("postComment").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        intCommentCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        tvWoowCount.setText(String.valueOf(intCommentCount));
    }
});
```

But the app crash.
Is there any solution to get the postComment Count?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few small problems in that snippet. This should work better (as long as `postID` has the correct value):

```
mPostDatabase.child(postID).child("postComment/default").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        tvWoowCount.setText(""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of using `tvWoowCount.setText(""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());` I used `tvWoowCount.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));` Besides, the `mPostDatabase.child(postID).child("postComment/default").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()` is not what I want. This will get the children under default. I want the children under postComment. BTW thanks for you remind.

Comment: @JayChuah it will give you the count on the "default" node because o `postComment/default` the slash default makes the differences